# navigate to a view controller from alert view from local notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uilocalnotification

On clicking alert view button which is presented by receiving local notification , I have to move to a view controller which is already embedded in a navigation controller. please advice how to perform this thanks in advance

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(nonnull UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Read more",nil];
        _SelectedPOI=[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"poiID"];
        alert.delegate=self;
        [alert show];
    }
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{ 
   if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
    // here i have to navigate to a view controller which is already embedded 
    in a navigation controller from another view controller
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIAlertView` is deprectaed. You should use `UIAlertController`. And to present a viewCOntroller or to push a viewController you have many options.

One way is to do it by using the storyboardID.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{ 
   if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
    // here i have to navigate to a view controller which is already embedded 
    in a navigation controller from another view controller

     OtherVC *vc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboard-id"];
     [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Make sure the OtherVC is a `UINavigationController` in your storyboard not the VC embedded in the nav controller.

Comment: Thanks ill use alertviewcontroller. Local notification is fired on cllocationmanager did update locations method. So the alertview controller may appear in any view controller when we reach the particular distance.. then i have to navigate to detail view controller which is already embedded in a navigation controller by clicking the first index of the alertview @Teja Nandamuri